# How make a framed Image?

Tags: java, android, image-processing

How make a framed Image?? i.e. put a frame around a bitmap Image??
the sample image is attached.. 
I have different frames. I want to put these frames around bitmap Images.. any suggestion will be helpful... 
( I am developing an Image Processing application and want to put framed effect)

[image]

Comment: ohh I forgot to appreciate peoples, I apologize for this. it will never happens in future, thank you pointing.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you do not expect people to help you with code or you would have accepted some of the answers to your previous questions. So here is a start:

1. Create an image capable of being tiled as the background of the frame.
2. Create a new canvas that is (Picture.Width + 50px * 2) x (Picture.Height + 50px * 2) in size. Replace 50px with whatever you want the border size to be.
3. Tile your background image over the whole canvas.
4. Put your bitmap on the canvas at point (50, 50). Replace 50 with your actual border size.

Good luck.